# Extracting javascript enabled data from page

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract coloured text in this [link](http://de.vroniplag.wikia.com/wiki/Aaf/008). I am using BeautifulSoup in python. The code is as follows:

```
import time, urllib2, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='http://de.vroniplag.wikia.com/wiki/Aaf/008'
def gethtml(link):
    time.sleep(2)
    req = urllib2.Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': "Magic Browser"})
    con = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    html = con.read()
    return html

soup=BeautifulSoup(gethtml(url),'html.parser')
print soup.findAll('span', attrs={"class": re.compile('fragmark')})
```

But the returned result is empty. How can I change it to make it work?

**UPDATE**:

I am using chromedriver, in the code as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

chromedriver = "./chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

driver.get('http://de.vroniplag.wikia.com/wiki/Aaf/008')
for tag in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[class^=fragmark]'):
    print(tag.text)
driver.quit()
```

But the browser opens. The result doesn't appear. I close the browser and then an error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use library that can interpret javascript. For example using [`selenium`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) because those elements with `fragmark1`, `fragmark2`, ... are created by the javascript.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome as Driver
# Replace with `Chrome` with your system browser

driver = Driver()
driver.get('http://de.vroniplag.wikia.com/wiki/Aaf/008')
for tag in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[class^=fragmark]'):
    print(tag.text)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for the answer. I don't have chrome. I am using chromedriver, can you help me? I have posted the new code as an UPDATE. Please do check

Comment: You can change `Chrome` with `FireFox` if you have Firefox installed. (PhantomJS, Edge, Opera, Ie, Safari, ... are also possible). `import selenium.webdriver; print(dir(selenium.webdriver))`